# Calculate term frequency on large data set

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, text

I want to calculate term frequency for a large list from an even larger data set.

The list (of pairs) is in the format of

> {
>        
>        source_term0, target_term0; 
>  
>        source_term1, target_term1; 
>        ... 
>        source_termX, target_termX 
> }

Where X is about 3.9 million.

The searching data set (pairs) is in the format of

> {
>        
>        source_sentence0, target_sentence0; 
>  
>        source_sentence1, target_sentence1; 
>        ... 
>        source_sentenceY, target_sentenceY 
> }

Where Y is about 12 million.

The term frequency is counted when source_termN is appeared in source_sentenceM AND target_termN is appeared in target_sentenceM.

My challenge is the computational time. I can run a nested loop, but it takes very long to complete. Just wondering there is any better algorithm for this case?

Comment: You want to do this for each term, right?

Comment: Yes, for each term pair.

Comment: How long are your sequences? Are source_terms unique? Or target_terms, or both? If not, do they repeat only a few times? Currently, the only idea of mine would need something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to build posting lists from the source sentences and target sentences. That is, for the source sentences, you have a dictionary that contains the term and a list of source sentences the term appears in. You do the same thing for the target sentences.

So given this:

```
source_sentence1 = "Joe married Sue."
target_sentence1 = "The bridge is blue."
source_sentence2 = "Sue has big feet."
target_sentence2 = "Blue water is best."
```

Then you have:

```
source_sentence_terms:
    joe, [1]
    married,[1]
    sue,[1,2]
    has,[2]
    big,[2]
    feet,[2]
target_sentence_temrs
    the,[1]
    bridge,[1]
    is,[1]
    blue,[1,2]
    water,[2]
    is,[2]
    best,[2]
```

Now you can go through your search terms. Let's say that your first pair is:

```
source_term1=sue, target_term1=bridge
```

You look "sue" up in the source_sentence_terms and you get the list `[1,2]`, meaning that the term occurs in those two source sentences.

You look "bridge" up in the target_sentence_terms and you get the list `[1]`.

Now you do a set intersection on those two lists and you wind up with `[1]`.

Building the posting lists from the sentences is O(n), where `n` is the total number of words in all of the sentences. You only have to do that once.

For each pair, you do two hash table lookups. Those are O(1). Doing a set intersection is O(m + n), where `m` and `n` are the sizes of the individual sets. It's hard to say how large those sets will be. It depends on the frequency of terms overall, and whether you're querying frequent terms.

Answer (score 0):

An idea comes to mind: sort the whole set of data. Basically, a good sorting algorithm is O(nlogn). You said you were currently at O(n^2), so this would be an improvement. Right now, when the data is sorted. You can iterate over them linearly.

I'm not sure if I understood your situation correctly, so this might be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> terms = new HashMap<>();
for each sourceTerm, targetTerm {
    // Java 7 or earlier
    Map<String, Integer> targetTerms = terms.get(sourceTerm);
    if (targetTerms == null)
        terms.put(sourceTerm, targetTerms = new HashMap<>());
    // Java 8
    Map<String, Integer> targetTerms =
        terms.computeIfAbsent(sourceTerm, HashMap::new);
    targetTerms.put(targetTerm, 0);
}

for each sourceSentence, targetSentence {
    String[] sourceSentenceTerms = sourceSentence.split("\\s+");
    String[] targetSentenceTerms = targetSentence.split("\\s+");
    for (String sourceSentenceTerm : sourceSentenceTerms) {
        for (String targetSentenceTerm : targetSentenceTerms) {
            Map<String, Integer> targetTerms = terms.get(sourceSentenceTerm);
            if (targetTerms != null) {
                // Java 7 or earlier
                Integer termFreq = targetTerms.get(targetSentenceTerm);
                if (termFreq != null)
                    targetTerms.put(targetSentenceTerm, termFreq + 1);
                // Java 8
                targetTerms.computeIfPresent(targetSentenceTerm,
                        (_, f) -> f + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```